# docker-compose volume not synced

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

### PROBLEM

I use docker-compose for development with Python/Flask. I want my host codebase to sync with one inside docker container but not...

### SITUATION

My working directory structure is below:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── app.py
└── requirements.txt
```

I made bind mount from host's current directory to container's `/app`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.3-alpine3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
  pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:9000 -w 4 app:app
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4649:9000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

When I access `http://localhost:4649` I can see correct response so Docker container is working well. However response don't update when I change `app.py`.

I inspected the container and the result is below

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/emp-mac-zakiooo/dev/jinja-pwa",
                "Destination": "/app",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

It looks very right so I have no idea about this problem

Answer (score 1):

OMG I found my files are correctly synced but gunicorn cached them so added `--reload` to `CMD` in `Dockerfile`, and finally it fixed.
Thank you for helping and soooo sorry for my foolishness...!

Comment: For me the problem was that the `WORKDIR` and `volumes` configuration didn't match. One of them showed `/usr/src/app` and the other showed `/app`. Once I made sure that both `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` both listed `/usr/src/app` it started to sync my container volume with my Mac OS volume. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by doing the following:

```
volumes:
    mount:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
          type: nfs
          o: addr=host.docker.internal,rw,nolock,hard,nfsvers=3
          device: ":${PWD}/path"
```

In your volume declaration within a service, you can do the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4649:9000"
    volumes:
      - mount:/app
```

Add the following to /etc/exports to enable docker access to your nfs volumes
`<path to $WORKSPACE> 127.0.0.1 -alldirs -mapall=0:80` once it's there you need to run `sudo nfsd restart` to include your changes.

if ever docker-compose stops responding when using NFS, restarting docker usually fixes it

I hope that this helps!